# why sometimes phpunit coverage is not available?

Tags: phpunit

I've configured a project to do code coverage. I really do not understand why some classes have n/a in coverage table.

[image]

Can someone explain me the reason?

Answer (score 1):

The two files you show in the picture do not have any executable code lines, OR the methods could also be marked with an annotation: `@codeCoverageIgnore` that will show 'n/a' and '0/0' for the lines covered column. The 'functions & method' column group may still show coverage for the methods though.

Comment: may some other annotation cause issues? There are also `@apidocs` and `@security` annotations.